# How Do I Use A Decimal Number In A Django URL Pattern?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I'd like to use a number with a decimal point in a Django URL pattern but I'm not sure whether it's actually possible (I'm not a regex expert).

Here's what I want to use for URLs:

```
/item/value/0.01
/item/value/0.05
```

Those URLs would show items valued at $0.01 or $0.05.  Sure, I could take the easy way out and pass the value in cents so it would be /item/value/1, but I'd like to receive the argument in my view as a decimal data type rather than as an integer (and I may have to deal with fractions of a cent at some point).  Is it possible to write a regex in a Django URL pattern that will handle this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It can be something like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   (r'^item/value/(?P<value>\d+\.\d{2})/$', 'myapp.views.byvalue'),
   ... more urls
)
```

url should not start with slash.

in views you can have function:

```
def byvalue(request,value='0.99'):
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except:
        ...
```

Comment: Please do not use a bare `except:` as this will eat every single error, often hiding bugs. You likely want to just catch `ValueError`'s (`except ValueError:`)

Answer (score 14):

I don't know about Django specifically, but this should match the URL:

```
r"^/item/value/(\d+\.\d+)$"
```

Comment: If you want to have ints and floats in *one* url, write something like this: `r"^/item/value/(\d+(?:\.\d+))$"`

Comment: +1 for a more generic answer (not limited to numbers with two digits after decimal)

Comment: @Boldewyn Ur solution doesnot work. Neither for ints nor for floats...i tried to used it but to no avail

Comment: @S.Ali Thanks. There's a `?` missing: `r"^/item/value/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$"` - for floats it should've worked before, however.

Answer (score 3):

If the values to be accepted are only $0.01 or $0.05, the harto's pattern may be specified like this:

```
r"^/item/value/(\d\.\d{2})$"
```

Comment: Thank you, each post added a little piece of the puzzle.  Evgeny had the magic bullet.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't use »

```
url(r"^item/value/(?P<dollar>\d+\.\d{1,2})$", views.show_item, name="show-item"),
```

> It will only match the **URL patterns** like `/item/value/0.01`, `/item/value/12.2` etc.
>
> It won't match **URL patterns** like `/item/value/1.223`, `/item/value/1.2679` etc.

### Better is to use »

```
url(r"^item/value/(?P<dollar>\d+\.\d+)$", views.show_item, name="show-item"),
```

> It will match **URL patterns** like  `/item/value/0.01`, `/item/value/1.22`,  `/item/value/10.223`, `/item/value/1.3` etc.

### Finally you can design your `views.py` something like

> This is just for an example.

```
# Make sure you have defined Item model (this is just an example)
# You use your own model name
from .models import Item 

def show_item(request, dollar):
    try:
        # Convert dollar(string) to dollar(float).
        # Which gets passed to show_item() if someone requests 
        # URL patterns like /item/value/0.01, /item/value/1.22 etc.
        dollar = float(dollar);

        # Fetch item from Database using its dollar value
        # You may use your own strategy (it's mine)
        item = Item.objects.get(dollar=dollar);

        # Make sure you have show_item.html.
        # Pass item to show_item.html (Django pawered page) so that it could be 
        # easily rendered using DTL (Django template language).
        return render(request, "show_item.html", {"item": item});
    except:
        # Make sure you have error.html page (In case if there's an error)
        return render(request, "error.html", {});
```

Comment: Big fan of this one. How can one make `r"^item/value/(?P<dollar>\d+\.\d+)$"` allow for a negative value?