# Django URL Pattern For Integer

Tags: python, regex, django-urls

I'm new to Python and Django.  I added a URLPattern into urls.py as below:

```
    url(r'^address_edit/(\d)/$', views.address_edit, name = "address_edit"),
```

I want my url accept a parameter of an integer with variable length, E.g. 0, 100, 1000, 99999, for the "id" of a db table.  However I found that I only accept only one digits in above pattern.  If i pass a integer not 1 digit only (e.g. 999999), it show an error

```
Reverse for 'address_edit' with arguments '(9999999,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['address_book/address_edit/(\\d)/$']
```

How do I construct the URL Pattern that let the program accept any number of digits integer from URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I Use A Decimal Number In A Django URL Pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128693/how-do-i-use-a-decimal-number-in-a-django-url-pattern)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The RegEx should have `+` modifier, like this

```
^address_edit/(\d+)/$
```

Quoting from [Python's RegEx documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax),

> #### '+'
>
> Causes the resulting RE to match 1 or more repetitions of the preceding RE. `ab+` will match `a` followed by any non-zero number of `b`s; it will not match just `a`.

`\d` will match any numeric digit (`0-9`). But it will match only once. To match it twice, you can either do `\d\d`. But as the number of digits to accept grows, you need to increase the number of `\d`s. But RegEx has a simpler way to do it. If you know the number of digits to accept then you can do

```
\d{3}
```

This will accept three consecutive numeric digits. What if you want to accept 3 to 5 digits? RegEx has that covered.

```
\d{3,5}
```

Simple, huh? :) Now, it will accept only 3 to 5 numeric digits (Note: Anything lesser than 3 also will not be matched). Now, you want to make sure that minimum 1 numeric digit, but maximum can be anything. What would you do? Just leave the range open ended, like this

```
\d{3,}
```

Now, RegEx engine will match minimum of 3 digits and maximum can be any number. If you want to match minimum one digit and maximum can be any number, then what would you do

```
\d{1,}
```

Correct :) Even this will work. But we have a shorthand notation to do the same, `+`. As mentioned on the documentation, it will match any non-zero number of digits.

Answer (score 30):

In Django >= 2.0 version, this is done in a more cleaner and simpler way like below.

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('address_edit/<int:id>/', views.address_edit, name = "address_edit"),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Though url() is still supported, its subject for deprecation soon and this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: If your int for some reason have a leading zero, it will be left out, which can cause problems: 0012 -> 12