# URL patterns (Django Programming)

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to generate a regex for just numbers. But for some reason the pattern doesn't seem to match. My code is:

```
url('^[\d\-]+/$', views.room, name='room'),
```

The request has to go to this expression. The HTML href for the above is:

```
<href="/polls/layout/103/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django URL Pattern For Integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420655/django-url-pattern-for-integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming polls/ is caught upstream in the project urls.py and you're editing the app urls.py.  You need to catch 'layout/' as well as '103'.

```
url('^layout/[0-9]+/$', views.room, name='room'),
```

If you need to capture the '103' for further processing within the view (likely), you might want to try something like:

```
url('^layout/(?P<room_number>[0-9]+)/$', views.room, name='room'),
```

where 'room_number' is an arg to the room class in your app's views.py.

Comment: Damn I forgot to add, I solved the problem. Silly mistake of mine. But yes. Thanks for the solution.