# View articles by author in Django blog

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a view that allows one to see all blog posts written by a particular author. Here's the URL pattern I'm using:

```
url(r'^user/(?P<username>[\w-]+)/$', views.user_articles, name="user_articles"),
```

And here's my view:

```
def user_articles(request, username):
    articles = Article.objects.filter(author=username).order_by('-date')
    return render(request, "articles/article_list.html", {'articles': articles})
```

This is returning the error:

```
ValueError at /articles/user/danny/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'danny'
```

Editing to add model as well:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = HTMLField('Body')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumb = models.ImageField(default="keys.jpg", blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None)
```

danny is a valid username, and it should be a string, not an integer, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering `author`, which is a ForeignKey to `auth.User` .

Your query should be

```
Article.objects.filter(author__username=username)
```

instead of ...`Article.objects.filter(author=username)`

Answer (score 2):

Post your model but I assume the association between models, is a Foreign Key. So 'author' on your model Article is likely an ID and not a string. So instead of the username 'danny' try retrieving 'danny's  ID.

Comment: Cool, I think this will put me on the right path. I'm just learning Django so this is all new to me. I updated with my model. Any syntax tips?

Comment: good luck. syntax fairly standard so far. and with your edit, author is an id and not a string. so use id when filtering, also you have to change the regex in your url function. have a look at this for integer regex in the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420655/django-url-pattern-for-integer?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa